# Using Valico JSON validator in my pallet

Tags: pallet, no-std, json

Currently I have problem that Valico is using std based packages like `serde` and `serde_json`. Is there any workaround to use this package?

UPDATE1:
I managed to [fork](https://github.com/brano-hozza/valico) repo and fix some dependencies but now i am getting these errors:
[image: error_1]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried building for WebAssembly:

- https://github.com/s-panferov/valico#building-for-other-targets

```rust
# Cargo.toml
valico = { version = "2", features = ["js"] }
```

Perhaps it gives you a no-std version.

Comment: Yep, now i tried to [fork](https://github.com/brano-hozza/valico) the repo and fix some dependencies but it looks like now that it is missing some traits (i will include them in edit of post)